# Cant drop db in single user mode?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tried

```
exec sp_dboption 'hipp_website_uat', 'single user', 'FALSE'
```

but i get

```
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_dboption'.
```

I have also tried setting the db to multi user in the db properties but I got

[image]

Does anyone know how I can drop this db or how to set it to multi-user mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to just get the users off - there is a 'Close Active Connections' option.

Have you tried checking that and then trying again ?

If you have sysadmin you can

`EXEC sp_who2`

and then `kill` the spids that are connected to the database.